# Obtain UV selection in Python?

Tags: python, uv

Using Python, can one select or find what is selected in the UV Image Editor?

I tried accessing the UV screen itself and found its `SpaceUVEditor` but got stuck there.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Note, UV's are stored in face loops, so 'BM_LOOPS_OF_FACE' is the correct iterator to use. Then from each loop you can access the UV customdata layer. However this is a bit odd that you are referencing C iterators in a Python question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The UV map being shown in the UV Image Editor is the active one, accessible through [`uv_layers.active`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.UVLoopLayers.html#bpy.types.UVLoopLayers.active) variable of active object's mesh data.

According to [API docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Mesh.html#mesh-data), [`loops`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.loops) and all UV maps in [`uv_layers`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.uv_layers) are aligned. Which means, if you have the indices of every selected [`MeshUVLoop`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.MeshUVLoop.html) within current mesh's UV map, you'll get the corresponding [`MeshLoop`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.MeshLoop.html) at the same indices within that mesh's list of loops. From there, you can get their vertices.

To make my explanation above clearer, here's a sample script that will print selected UV loops' vertex coordinates to console. The script won't work if `use_uv_select_sync` button in UV Image Editor's header is toggled on, in which case `MeshUVLoop`'s `select` property is ignored.

```
import bpy

# UV data is accessible only in object mode
prev_mode = bpy.context.object.mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# Update vertex selection properties, in case the script wasn't run in
# object mode
bpy.context.object.update_from_editmode()

# Active object assumed to be a mesh and already have a UV map
mesh = bpy.context.object.data
uv_map = mesh.uv_layers.active
selected_loops = []
selected_vertices = set()

for index, uv_loop in enumerate(uv_map.data):
    if(uv_loop.select):
        selected_loops.append(index)

for loop_index in selected_loops:
    selected_vertices.add(mesh.loops[loop_index].vertex_index)

for vertex_index in selected_vertices:
    print(mesh.vertices[vertex_index].co)

print('*' * 20)

# Restore whatever mode the object is in previously
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=prev_mode)
```

Answer (score 5):

Blender comes with a template which deals with UV selection, see:

*Templates > Python > Operator Mesh UV*

The body of this template:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = context.active_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.verify()
bm.faces.layers.tex.verify()  # currently blender needs both layers.

# adjust UVs
for f in bm.faces:
    for l in f.loops:
        luv = l[uv_layer]
        if luv.select:
            # apply the location of the vertex as a UV
            luv.uv = l.vert.co.xy

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```