# Halfedge UV-coordinates

Tags: python, uv, bmesh

I am programming a Python script, which takes a mesh from a external tool and adds it to the blender scene.

I transmit a texture and the mesh, and it actually works. But I have trouble with the UV coordinates.

The external tool handles the uv-coordinates per halfedge. This results in multiple uv coordinates for a vertex but all referencing the same texture. This is used for hard seams in the texture.

Now I need to reproduce this using Blender. How do I achieve this?

Using the bmesh module I can iterate over the loops of the mesh, but I don't know how to utilize this for my purpose.

Is there a halfedge support in Blender? Or can I set multiple UV-coords per vertex for one texture on a mesh?

Thank you for your help!

Greetings, Dragonseel

Comment: There are similar quiestions about UV's, Multuiple UV's per vertex are suppoeted, see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3532/obtain-uv-selection-in-python and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/711/how-to-add-a-uv-map-to-a-mesh-using-python

Comment: Note, the **Halfedge** part of this question is irrelevant.