# How to get vertexs indexes of active UV polygon?

Tags: python, uv

How can I get vertex indices of the current polygon selected in the mesh, not the one currently selected in the UV editor, via the Python API?

[image: active uv polygon]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obtain UV selection in Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3532/obtain-uv-selection-in-python)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady No.

Comment: A gray area in the UV editor is active face of a mesh, not UV. Since there is no similar to *Active Element* in the pivot selection of the UV editor's header, I guess that there is no concept of active in UV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tetii stated, that grey face is the active face of a mesh. In Python you can get that face with `bpy.context.object.data.polygons.active`. Make sure you do it in Object Mode, otherwise `.active` can point to an old value.

To get the vertices of the active face in the mesh and the UV map, you can do like this (see [Blender docs about Mesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html)):

```
import bpy

# Force object mode, to ensure active polygon is up to date
obj_mode = bpy.context.active_object.mode
if obj_mode != 'OBJECT':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# Get active object
obj = bpy.context.object.data

# Get active uv map
uv_layer = obj.uv_layers.active.data

# Get active polygon
active_poly = obj.polygons[obj.polygons.active]

# Get mesh vertices and uv vertices
# See: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html
for loop_index in active_poly.loop_indices:
    # You can access the mesh vertices with: obj.vertices[vertex_index]
    vertex_index = obj.loops[loop_index].vertex_index
    print(f'Mesh vertex index: {vertex_index}')
    
    # Get UV coordinates of vertex
    print(f'UV vertex at: {uv_layer[loop_index].uv}')


# Return to original mode
if obj_mode != 'OBJECT':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=obj_mode)
```